# VBA CalculatedFields Pivot USe Variables as Field References?

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I know how to create calculated fields by hard coding the reference to a specific field in a pivot table but I am having trouble (getting 1004 error) with using a variable that holds a string with the name of the field reference such as below:

This is what I would like to do, but it doesn't work/errors out!

```
Dim currMonth As String
currMonth = "Jan-14"
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").CalculatedFields.Add "YTD2014", _
currMonth, True
```

This works fine

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable6").CalculatedFields.Add "YTD2014", _
    "='Jan-14'", True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**currMonth** is initialized as:

```
currMonth = "Jan-14"
```

but should be:

```
currMonth = "='Jan-14'"
```

Do you see the difference?

Comment: Thanks for the help, but same situation, "Run-Time Error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error" :(

Comment: Same issue, I appreciate your help, I feel like I am on the cusp of it, maybe calculatedfields don't allow vba variables as substitutes to actual text?

Comment: I'm an idiot, got it working, there was a field already created with that name so it was hiccuping while trying to recreate it, thanks for your help!